# How to create a chained function with "use strict" mode?

Tags: javascript

The code below is a minimal test of a chained function as explained [here](https://schier.co/blog/2013/11/14/method-chaining-in-javascript.html).

```
function a(v1) {
    this.v = v1
    this.b = function (v2) {
        alert("v1="+this.v+" and v2="+v2);
    };
    return this;
}

a(1).b(1);
```

It's working well this way but since I add the `"use strict";` directive the script failed with error `TypeError: this is undefined`

I know it is a common error in strict mode but I haven't found any idea about how getting around it.

Any help would be very appreciate :)

Comment: You have to define a class and "a" must be a method of that class. Then you have to instantiate an object of that class with the "new" keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take an instance of the function with [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) and work with it.

It works, because [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is bound to the newly created object.

```js
'use strict';

function a(v1) {
    this.v = v1
    this.b = function (v2) {
        console.log("v1="+this.v+" and v2="+v2);
    };
    //return this; // instancable functions always return this
}

new a(1).b(1);
```

Comment: Thanks for this helping answer. I needed to keep the call of the chained function as is and I found the solution by passing by an intermediate function that create the object with `new operator`.